# How does os.stat(path).st_mtime actually get file modified time?

Tags: python, python-3.6, filemtime

In this example, I'm using Python 3.6.5 installed using `pyenv` in an OSX shell.

I've been toying around with some proof of concept file watching code and I figured using a delta of a file's current and last measured `st_mtime` would be enough to "detect" that a file has changed.

The code:

```python
import os


def main():
    file_path = 'myfile.txt'
    last_modified = os.stat(file_path).st_mtime
    while True:
        check_last_modified = os.stat(file_path).st_mtime
        delta = check_last_modified - last_modified

        if delta != 0.0:
            print("File was modified.")

        last_modified = check_last_modified



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The weird thing is different types of basic file modification operations will result in "File was modified." printing more than once.

Assuming `myfile.txt` exists, I get a different number of prints based on the operation:

It prints 1 time with: `$ touch myfile.txt`

It prints 2 times with: `$ echo "" > myfile.txt`.

It prints 1 time with:

```
$ cat <<EOF > myfile.txt
> EOF
```

It prints 2 times with (empty line):

```
$ cat <<EOF > myfile.txt
>
> EOF
```

It prints 1 time using python to write an empty string:

```python
def main():
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as _file:
        _file.write('')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It prints 2 times using python to write a non-empty string:

```python
def main():
    with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as _file:
        _file.write('a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The biggest difference seems to be the presence of a string other than a newline, but seeing as how the `echo` command results in two prints I'm not inclined to believe it's bound to that in any way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is a busy waiting loop so it can catch several time changes very quickly.

When python creates the file (`open`) it sets/updates the creation time.

But the creation time is updated once more when closing the file. Which explains you catch 2 time updates.

`touch` just sets the modification time once, but `echo` acts the same as your python script: set modification time when creating/opening the existing file, and set it again when closing it.

The busy loop and the open/close operations create a race conditions and the number of time updates you're seeing is undefined (which explains that your script misses one update in a `cat` command where the data is small)

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it was something as simple as this. Your answer makes complete sense.